# Can't extract rss feed item title

Tags: php, rss, ebay-api

I'm using a php code to extract the title of an ebay affiliate (Partner Network) rss, but I'm having no success. What am I doing wrong?
By the way, is it possible to link the title too?

PHP

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTMLFile('http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=%28jewelry%2Ccraft%2Cclothing%2Cshoes%2Cdiy%29&sortOrder=BestMatch&programid=1&campaignid=5337945426&toolid=10039&listingType1=All&lgeo=1&topRatedSeller=true&hideDuplicateItems=true&entriesPerPage=2&feedType=rss');   

$products = array();

    //Loop through each <td> tag in the dom and extract inner html

foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('td') as $p) {
    $children  = $p->childNodes;
    $phtml = '';
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $phtml.= $p->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }       

     echo '<div id="mainproductafilioright1"><div class="product">' . $phtml . '</div></div>';      
}
?>
```

Comment: Uhhhh `getElementsByTagName('td')` seeing your are getting an RSS feed there are no `td` tags ... you just copied some code and didn't edit it at all to do what you wanted it to do.

Comment: It's because that's an old code I had configured before for another rss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right way. While checking the feed page I could see that the `td` elements are inside the `<![CDATA[`. but the title is outside it, that's why you can't get the title.

Try this temporary solution (This is a completely new code, not to be inserted with the older one):

```
$feedurl = "http://rest.ebay.com/epn/v1/find/item.rss?keyword=%28jewelry%2Ccraft%2Cclothing%2Cshoes%2Cdiy%29&sortOrder=BestMatch&programid=1&campaignid=5337945426&toolid=10039&listingType1=All&lgeo=1&topRatedSeller=true&hideDuplicateItems=true&entriesPerPage=8&feedType=rss";

$rss = simplexml_load_file($feedurl);

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {

$link = $item->link;

$title = $item->title;

$description = $item->description;

}
```

You can output it using `print`:

`print = $description;`

Answer (score 0):

Would comment but not enough rep.

There are no td elements in that feed. It's also not an HTML file.

Instead:

- Load as XML
- Create XPath expression to select title nodes
- Iterate returned nodes and make sure they're actual DOM nodes
- Extract text value of node.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("http://www.longurl.com");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$items = $xpath->query("/rss/channel/item/title");

foreach($items as $item) {
    if(XML_ELEMENT_NODE === $item->nodeType) {
        echo '<div id="mainproductafilioright1"><div class="product">' . $item->textContent . '</div></div>';
    }
}
```